# override css with !important having a class attribute without adding id to increase specificity

Tags: css

```
<div class="class1"></div>
```

I have a css rule

```
.class1{
text-align: left !important;
}
```

How do I override this rule without adding a style with the same class name ? I have tried adding the css below the above rule which doesn't work :

```css
.class1 {
  text-align: left !important;
}

.class2 {
  text-align: center !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="class1 class2"> text</div>
```

I can only add a class to this element.

Will it make a difference if class1 rule has been defined in `<style>` tag in html head

Comment: share the HTML .

Comment: You can't apply class2 to the div in your html without calling it.

Comment: your code works fine

Comment: Will it make a difference if class1 rule has been defined in <style> tag in html head

Comment: Yes that is the key. if class1 is defined in <style> it has higher priority than others in css file. You'd need to specify it more

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

First Way if you have only one class ( class1 ). then follow the below code

```
<div class="class1"></div>
.class1{
  text-align: left !important;
}
div.class1{
  text-align: center !important;
}
```

Second Way if you have two class ( class1 class2 ) then follow the below code

```
<div class="class1 class2"></div>

.class1{
  text-align: left !important;
}
.class2{
  text-align: center !important;
}
```

Comment: did u miss a . before class1 in second one ?

Comment: accepting this answer since I got the idea from this one. I used div.class2{} and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

```
HTML:
<div class="class1 class2">text</div>

CSS:
.class1{
text-align: left !important;
}

.class2{
text-align: center !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have another css file somewhere else defining the .class1 at a higher priority. In this case it can't be done without specifying more. You can specify by an id, or use inline style:

```
<div class="class1" style="text-align: center !important"> text2</div>
```

or avoid using class1, but instead create another class that extend it so it will have everything else in class1 but override the text-align:

```
.class2 {
  @extend .class1;
  text-align: center !important;
}
```

and have the html as

```
<div class="class2"> text2</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this first way-

```css
.class1{ text-align: left !important;}
.class2{ text-align: center !important;}
```

```html
<div class="class1">Class 1</div>
<div class="class1 class2">Class 2</div>
```

You can try this Second way-

```css
.class1{ text-align: left !important;}
div.class1{ text-align: center !important;}
```

```html
<div class="class1">Class 1</div>
```

Comment: why copying another answer